# Second quantisation of single-body operator - Why multiplying operators gives different results

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, second-quantization

It seems clear that the second quatisation form of a single-body operator, say the position operator $\hat{\vec r}$, looks like
$$\hat{\vec r}=\sum_{\vec r} \vec{r} a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}}a_{\vec{r}} \qquad(1)$$
and that
$$\hat{\vec r^2}=\sum_{\vec r} \vec{r}^2 a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}}a_{\vec{r}} \qquad(2)$$
but if I try to calculate $\hat{\vec r^2}$ with the help of eq.(1), it gives
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\vec r^2}&= \sum_{\vec r} \vec{r} a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}}a_{\vec{r}} \sum_{\vec r^\prime} \vec{r}^\prime a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}^\prime}a_{\vec{r}^\prime} \\
&= \sum_{{\vec r}\vec r^\prime} \vec{r}\vec{r}^\prime a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}}a_{\vec{r}} a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}^\prime}a_{\vec{r}^\prime}\\
&= \sum_{{\vec r}\vec r^\prime} \vec{r}\vec{r}^\prime a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}}(\delta_{\vec{r},\vec{r}^\prime}\pm a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}^\prime}a_{\vec{r}}) a_{\vec{r}^\prime}\\
&=\sum_{\vec r} \vec{r}^2 a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}}a_{\vec{r}} \pm \sum_{{\vec r}\vec r^\prime} \vec{r}\vec{r}^\prime a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}} a^{\dagger}_{\vec{r}^\prime} a_{\vec{r}} a_{\vec{r}^\prime} \qquad (3)
\end{align}
$$
which disobeys eq.(2). Why is this happenning? How comes the second term of eq.(3)?

Comment: I think you're confusing some things. First of all, in $(1)$ it should be a matrix element of $r$ in the sum and second it should be an integral, but okay. Most importantly, I think your issue comes down to the fact that the square of the second-quantized operator is not the same as the second-quantized operator squared... Indeed, the second quantized operator arising from e.g. the identity operator on the single-particle Hilbert space is the particle operator $N$ on Fock space, and $N^2\neq N$, where $N$ on the RHS is constructed from the identity operator squared.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you meant to say that the $r$ in the sum is the matrix element, I misread that.

Comment: Your first equality (1) is not an equality.  That is the issue. On the left-hand side, you have a single-particle operator, and on the right-hand side you have a *many*-particle operator. These can't be equal.

Comment: @march Well, it might be an abuse of notation, tho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ambiguity already exists in first quantization. Say you have $n$ particles with each of them their position operator $\hat r_1…\hat r_n$. While it makes sense to define:
$$
\hat r=\sum_i\hat r_i
$$
you have to possible definitions for defining $\hat r^2$. The one corresponding to (2) is:
$$
\hat{r^2}=\sum_i\hat r_i^2
$$
and the one corresponding to (3) is:
$$
\hat r^2=\left(\sum_i\hat r_i\right)^2
$$
which differ in a similar way by twice the dot product. The relevance of one operator over the other depends on the problem at hand.

Hope this helps.